# QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, qfiledialog

Получить пути файлов, которые я выбираю

```
def ChoiceImages(self):
    self.FacesOfPerson = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, "Выберите картинку с лицами фантомов", None, "*.png *.jpg")

    print(self.FacesOfPerson)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем примере будет так:

```
    def ChoiceImages(self):
        self.FacesOfPerson = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, "Выберите картинку с лицами фантомов", None, "*.png *.jpg")
        import os        
        folder = os.path.dirname(self.FacesOfPerson[0])                                  # <---------        
        print("folder =", folder)        
        #print(self.FacesOfPerson)
```

В моем примере:

```
    import os        
    folder = os.path.dirname(filenames[0])                                  # <---------        
    print("folder =", folder)        
    self.plainTextEdit.appendHtml("""<br>пути файлов, которые я выбираю: 
                                   <b>{}</b> """
                                  "".format(folder))
```

Вот пример:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Form(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.plainTextEdit = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.plainTextEdit.setFont(QFont('Arial', 11))


        openDirButton = QPushButton("Open Directory")
        openDirButton.clicked.connect(self.getDirectory)

        getFileNameButton = QPushButton("Open File")
        getFileNameButton.clicked.connect(self.getFileName)

        getFileNamesButton = QPushButton("Open Files")
        getFileNamesButton.clicked.connect(self.getFileNames)

        saveFileNameButton = QPushButton("Save File")
        saveFileNameButton.clicked.connect(self.saveFile)

        layoutV = QVBoxLayout()
        layoutV.addWidget(openDirButton)
        layoutV.addWidget(getFileNameButton)
        layoutV.addWidget(getFileNamesButton)
        layoutV.addWidget(saveFileNameButton)

        layoutH = QHBoxLayout()
        layoutH.addLayout(layoutV)
        layoutH.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit)

        centerWidget = QWidget()
        centerWidget.setLayout(layoutH) 
        self.setCentralWidget(centerWidget)

        self.resize(740,480)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5-QFileDialog")

    def getDirectory(self):
        dirlist = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,"Выбрать папку",".")
        self.plainTextEdit.appendHtml("<br>Выбрали папку: <b>{}</b>".format(dirlist))

    def getFileName(self):
        filename, filetype = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,
                             "Выбрать файл",
                             ".",
                             "Text Files(*.txt);;JPEG Files(*.jpeg);;\
                             PNG Files(*.png);;GIF File(*.gif);;All Files(*)")
        self.plainTextEdit.appendHtml("<br>Выбрали файл: <b>{}</b> <br> <b>{:*^54}</b>"
                                      "".format(filename, filetype))

    def getFileNames(self):
        filenames, ok = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self,
                             "Выберите несколько файлов",
                             ".",
                             "All Files(*.*)")
        self.plainTextEdit.appendHtml("""<br>Выбрали несколько файлов: 
                                       <b>{}</b> <br> <b>{:*^80}</b>"""
                                      "".format(filenames, ok))
# +++      
        import os        
        folder = os.path.dirname(filenames[0])                                  # <---------        
        print("folder =", folder)        
        self.plainTextEdit.appendHtml("""<br>пути файлов, которые я выбираю: 
                                       <b>{}</b> """
                                      "".format(folder))        
# +++                                      

    def saveFile(self):
        filename, ok = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,
                             "Сохранить файл",
                             ".",
                             "All Files(*.*)")
        self.plainTextEdit.appendHtml("<br>Сохранить файл: <b>{}</b> <br> <b>{:*^54}</b>"
                                      "".format(filename, ok))
        """
        if filename: 
            # Видимо лучше сохранить каким-то досовскими методами

            file = open(filename,'wb')
            file.write(...)
            file.close()
        """

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Form()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример использования стандартного диалогового окна.

Очень полный Qt стандартный диалог, включая 
QInputDialog, QColorDialog, QFontDialog, QMessageBox, QOpenFileDialog ...

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class DialogOptionsWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DialogOptionsWidget,self).__init__(parent)
    def addCheckBox(self, text, value):
        pass
    def addSpacer():
        pass
    def value():
        pass


class StandardDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(StandardDialog,self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle("Standard Dialog")
        frameStyle = QFrame.Sunken | QFrame.Panel
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        toolbox    = QToolBox()
        mainLayout.addWidget(toolbox)

        self.errorMessageDialog  = QErrorMessage(self)
        pushButton_integer       = QPushButton("QInputDialog.get&Int()")
        pushButton_double        = QPushButton("QInputDialog.get&Double()")
        pushButton_item          = QPushButton("QInputDialog.getIte&m()")
        pushButton_text          = QPushButton("QInputDialog.get&Text()")
        pushButton_multiLineText = QPushButton("QInputDialog.get&MultiLineText()")
        pushButton_color         = QPushButton("QColorDialog.get&Color()")
        pushButton_font          = QPushButton("QFontDialog.get&Font()")
        pushButton_directory     = QPushButton("QFileDialog.getE&xistingDirectory()")
        pushButton_openFileName  = QPushButton("QFileDialog.get&OpenFileName()")
        pushButton_openFileNames = QPushButton("QFileDialog.&getOpenFileNames()")
        pushButton_saveFileName  = QPushButton("QFileDialog.get&SaveFileName()")
        pushButton_critical      = QPushButton("QMessageBox.critica&l()")
        pushButton_information   = QPushButton("QMessageBox.i&nformation()")
        pushButton_question      = QPushButton("QQMessageBox.&question()")
        pushButton_warning       = QPushButton("QMessageBox.&warning()")
        pushButton_error         = QPushButton("QErrorMessage.showM&essage()")

        self.label_integer = QLabel()
        self.label_double        = QLabel()
        self.label_item          = QLabel()
        self.label_text          = QLabel()
        self.label_multiLineText = QLabel()
        self.label_color         = QLabel()
        self.label_font          = QLabel()
        self.label_directory     = QLabel()
        self.label_openFileName  = QLabel()
        self.label_openFileNames = QLabel()
        self.label_saveFileName  = QLabel()
        self.label_critical      = QLabel()
        self.label_information   = QLabel()
        self.label_question      = QLabel()
        self.label_warning       = QLabel()
        self.label_error         = QLabel()

        self.label_integer.setFrameStyle(frameStyle)
        self.label_double.setFrameStyle(frameStyle)
        self.label_item.setFrameStyle(frameStyle)
        self.label_text.setFrameStyle(frameStyle)
        self.label_multiLineText.setFrameStyle(frameStyle)
        self.label_color.setFrameStyle(frameStyle)
        self.label_font.setFrameStyle(frameStyle)
        self.label_directory.setFrameStyle(frameStyle)
        self.label_openFileName.setFrameStyle(frameStyle)
        self.label_openFileNames.setFrameStyle(frameStyle)
        self.label_saveFileName.setFrameStyle(frameStyle)
        self.label_critical.setFrameStyle(frameStyle)
        self.label_information.setFrameStyle(frameStyle)
        self.label_question.setFrameStyle(frameStyle)
        self.label_warning.setFrameStyle(frameStyle)
        self.label_error.setFrameStyle(frameStyle)

        page = QWidget()
        layout = QGridLayout(page)
        layout.setColumnStretch(1,1)
        layout.setColumnMinimumWidth(1,250)
        layout.addWidget(pushButton_integer,0,0)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_integer,0,1)
        layout.addWidget(pushButton_double,1,0)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_double,1,1)
        layout.addWidget(pushButton_item,2,0)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_item,2,1)
        layout.addWidget(pushButton_text,3,0)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_text,3,1)
        layout.addWidget(pushButton_multiLineText,4,0)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_multiLineText,4,1)
        layout.addItem(QSpacerItem(0,0,QSizePolicy.Ignored,QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding),5,0)
        toolbox.addItem(page, "Input Dialog")

        page   = QWidget()
        layout = QGridLayout(page)
        layout.setColumnStretch(1,1)
        #layout.setColumnMinimumWidth(1,250)
        layout.addWidget(pushButton_color,0,0)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_color,0,1)
        colorDialogOptionsWidget = DialogOptionsWidget()
        colorDialogOptionsWidget.addCheckBox("Не использовать собственный диалог", 
                                              QColorDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
        colorDialogOptionsWidget.addCheckBox("Показать альфа-канал" , QColorDialog.ShowAlphaChannel)
        colorDialogOptionsWidget.addCheckBox("No buttons" , QColorDialog.NoButtons)
        layout.addItem(QSpacerItem(0,0,QSizePolicy.Ignored,QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding),1,0)
        layout.addWidget(colorDialogOptionsWidget, 2, 0, 1 ,2)
        toolbox.addItem(page, "Color Dialog")

        page   = QWidget()
        layout = QGridLayout(page)
        layout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(pushButton_font, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_font, 0, 1)
        fontDialogOptionsWidget = DialogOptionsWidget()
        fontDialogOptionsWidget.addCheckBox("Do not use native dialog", QFontDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
        fontDialogOptionsWidget.addCheckBox("No buttons", QFontDialog.NoButtons)
        layout.addItem(QSpacerItem(0, 0, QSizePolicy.Ignored, QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding), 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(fontDialogOptionsWidget, 2, 0, 1 ,2)
        toolbox.addItem(page, "Font Dialog")

        page   = QWidget()
        layout = QGridLayout(page)
        layout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(pushButton_directory, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_directory, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(pushButton_openFileName, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_openFileName, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(pushButton_openFileNames, 2, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_openFileNames, 2, 1)
        layout.addWidget(pushButton_saveFileName, 3, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_saveFileName, 3, 1)

        fileDialogOptionsWidget = DialogOptionsWidget()
        fileDialogOptionsWidget.addCheckBox("Do not use native dialog", QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
        fileDialogOptionsWidget.addCheckBox("Show directories only", QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly)
        fileDialogOptionsWidget.addCheckBox("Do not resolve symlinks", QFileDialog.DontResolveSymlinks)
        fileDialogOptionsWidget.addCheckBox("Do not confirm overwrite", QFileDialog.DontConfirmOverwrite)
        fileDialogOptionsWidget.addCheckBox("Do not use sheet", QFileDialog.DontUseSheet)
        fileDialogOptionsWidget.addCheckBox("Readonly", QFileDialog.ReadOnly)
        fileDialogOptionsWidget.addCheckBox("Hide name filter details", QFileDialog.HideNameFilterDetails)
        layout.addItem(QSpacerItem(0, 0, QSizePolicy.Ignored, QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding), 4, 0)
        layout.addWidget(fileDialogOptionsWidget, 5, 0, 1 ,2)
        toolbox.addItem(page, "File Dialogs")

        page   = QWidget()
        layout = QGridLayout(page)
        layout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(pushButton_critical, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_critical, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(pushButton_information, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_information, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(pushButton_question, 2, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_question, 2, 1)
        layout.addWidget(pushButton_warning, 3, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_warning, 3, 1)
        layout.addWidget(pushButton_error, 4, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_error, 4, 1)
        layout.addItem(QSpacerItem(0, 0, QSizePolicy.Ignored, QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding), 5, 0)
        toolbox.addItem(page, "Message Boxes")

        pushButton_integer.clicked.connect(self.setInteger)
        pushButton_double.clicked.connect(self.setDouble)
        pushButton_item.clicked.connect(self.setItem)
        pushButton_text.clicked.connect(self.setText)
        pushButton_multiLineText.clicked.connect(self.setMultiLineText)
        pushButton_color.clicked.connect(self.setColor)
        pushButton_font.clicked.connect(self.setFont)
        pushButton_directory.clicked.connect(self.setExistingDirectory)
        pushButton_openFileName.clicked.connect(self.setOpenFileName)
        pushButton_openFileNames.clicked.connect(self.setOpenFileNames)
        pushButton_saveFileName.clicked.connect(self.setSaveFileName)
        pushButton_critical.clicked.connect(self.criticalMessage)
        pushButton_information.clicked.connect(self.informationMessage)
        pushButton_question.clicked.connect(self.questionMessage)
        pushButton_warning.clicked.connect(self.warningMessage)
        pushButton_error.clicked.connect(self.errorMessage)

    # Input диалоговое окно Принять целое число
    def setInteger(self):
        intNum, ok = QInputDialog.getInt(self, "QInputDialog.getInteger()","Процент:", 25, 0, 100, 1)
        if ok:
            self.label_integer.setText(str(intNum))

    # Процент
    def setDouble(self):
        doubleNum, ok = QInputDialog.getDouble(self, "QInputDialog.getDouble()", 
                                               "Количество:", 37.56, -10000, 10000, 2)
        if ok:
            self.label_double.setText(str(doubleNum))

    # Input диалоговое окно, чтобы взять элементы списка
    def setItem(self):
        items = ["Spring", "Summer", "Fall", "Winter"]
        item, ok = QInputDialog.getItem(self, "QInputDialog.getItem()","Время года:", items, 0, False)
        if ok and item:
            self.label_item.setText(item)

    # Диалоговое окно ввода
    def setText(self):
        text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, "QInputDialog.getText()", 
                                        "User name:", 
                                        QLineEdit.Normal, QDir.home().dirName())
        if ok and text:
            self.label_text.setText(text)

    # Введите диалоговое окно ввода нескольких строк текста.
    def setMultiLineText(self):
        text, ok = QInputDialog.getMultiLineText(self, "QInputDialog.getMultiLineText()", "Address:", "John Doe\nFreedom Street")
        if ok and text:
            self.label_multiLineText.setText(text)

    # Диалоговое окно цвета
    def setColor(self):
        #options = QColorDialog.ColorDialogOptions(QFlag.QFlag(colorDialogOptionsWidget.value()))
        color = QColorDialog.getColor(Qt.green, self, "Select Color")
        if color.isValid():
           self.label_color.setText(color.name())
           self.label_color.setPalette(QPalette(color))
           self.label_color.setAutoFillBackground(True)

    # Диалоговое окно Font
    def setFont(self):
        #options = QFontDialog.FontDialogOptions(QFlag(fontDialogOptionsWidget.value()))
        #font, ok = QFontDialog.getFont(ok, QFont(self.label_font.text()), self, "Select Font",options)
        font, ok = QFontDialog.getFont()
        if ok:
            self.label_font.setText(font.key())
            self.label_font.setFont(font)

    # Диалог каталога
    def setExistingDirectory(self):
        #options = QFileDialog.Options(QFlag(fileDialogOptionsWidget->value()))
        #options |= QFileDialog.DontResolveSymlinks | QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly
        directory = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,
                    "QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory()",
                    self.label_directory.text())
        if directory:
            self.label_directory.setText(directory)

    # Открыть диалоговое окно файла
    def setOpenFileName(self):
        #options = QFileDialog.Options(QFlag(fileDialogOptionsWidget.value()))
        #selectedFilter
        fileName, filetype = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,
                            "QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()",
                            self.label_openFileName.text(),
                            "All Files (*);;Text Files (*.txt)")
        if fileName:
            self.label_openFileName.setText(fileName)

    # Откройте диалоговое окно `Файл`. Сделайте набор имен файлов.
    def setOpenFileNames(self):
        #options = QFileDialog.Options(QFlag(fileDialogOptionsWidget.value()))
        #selectedFilter
        openFilesPath = "E:/_Qt/PyQt/"
        files, ok = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self,
                        "QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames()",
                        openFilesPath,
                        "All Files (*);;Text Files (*.txt)")
        if len(files):
            self.label_openFileNames.setText(", ".join(files))

    # Диалоговое окно `Сохранить файл`
    def setSaveFileName(self):
        #options = QFileDialog.Options(QFlag(fileDialogOptionsWidget.value()))
        #selectedFilter
        fileName, ok = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,
                     "QFileDialog.getSaveFileName()",
                     self.label_saveFileName.text(),
                     "All Files (*);;Text Files (*.txt)")
        if fileName:
            self.label_saveFileName.setText(fileName)

    def criticalMessage(self):
        #reply = QMessageBox.StandardButton()
        MESSAGE = "Критика!"
        reply = QMessageBox.critical(self,
                "QMessageBox.critical()",
                MESSAGE,
                QMessageBox.Abort | QMessageBox.Retry | QMessageBox.Ignore)
        if reply == QMessageBox.Abort:
            self.label_critical.setText("Abort")
        elif reply == QMessageBox.Retry:
            self.label_critical.setText("Retry")
        else:
            self.label_critical.setText("Ignore")

    def informationMessage(self):
        MESSAGE = "Информация"
        reply = QMessageBox.information(self, "QMessageBox.information()", MESSAGE)
        if reply == QMessageBox.Ok:
            self.label_information.setText("OK")
        else:
            self.label_information.setText("Escape")

    def questionMessage(self):
        MESSAGE = "Сомнение"
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, "QMessageBox.question()",
                        MESSAGE,
                        QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No | QMessageBox.Cancel)
        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            self.label_question.setText("Yes")
        elif reply == QMessageBox.No:
            self.label_question.setText("No")
        else:
            self.label_question.setText("Cancel")

    def warningMessage(self):
        MESSAGE = "Предупреждающий текст"
        msgBox = QMessageBox(QMessageBox.Warning,
                            "QMessageBox.warning()",
                            MESSAGE,
                            QMessageBox.Retry | QMessageBox.Discard | QMessageBox.Cancel,
                            self)
        msgBox.setDetailedText("Подробнее ...")
        #msgBox.addButton("Save &Again", QMessageBox.AcceptRole)
        #msgBox.addButton("&Continue", QMessageBox.RejectRole)
        if msgBox.exec() == QMessageBox.AcceptRole:
            self.label_warning.setText("Retry")
        else:
            self.label_warning.setText("Abort")

    def errorMessage(self):
        self.errorMessageDialog.showMessage(
             "В этом диалоговом окне отображаются и запоминаются сообщения об ошибках. "
             "Если флажок установлен (как по умолчанию), "
             "показанное сообщение будет показано снова, "
             "но если пользователь отключает окно, сообщение "
             "больше не появится, если QErrorMessage.showMessage() "
             "вызывается с тем же сообщением.")
        self.label_error.setText("Если флажок снят, сообщение "
                                 "больше не появится.")


app  = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = StandardDialog()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я конечно всё понимаю, но можно конкретно мою проблему?

Comment: Извини, я добавил новый пример